# Keyboard shortcut to scroll window up and down?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, macos

In Windows, there's a really useful keyboard shortcut for scrolling the current text editor window up or down by one line *without moving the cursor*. This appears to be implemented in the operating system because it works in almost every application.

The shortcut is <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↑ Up Arrow</kbd> to move the viewport up the document and <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓ Down Arrow</kbd> to move the viewport down the document.

Is there something similar in OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You can try <kbd>⇞ page up</kbd> and <kbd>⇟ page down</kbd>, which usual pages one whole page back and forth. I don't think there is a system wide shortcut to scroll by line.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [official list of macOS keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) only has <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to "move up one line" and <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to "move down one line", but it seems to work exacly like <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>, moving the cursor.